my code doesn't change key of gun in project python
When I press the first key, it works, but when I try to change the key it is not changing, it remains on the first key that was pressed.
example: I press the numpad1 key and it works, when I press numpad2 it doesn't change, it remains on the numpad1 key, I would like it to change
def load_weapon(name, recoil, rpm):
    return Weapon(name, recoil, rpm)

def exec_control(gun, k):
    print(f"CurrentWeapon:\t{gun.name}\nMagazineSize:\t{len(gun.recoil)}\nRPM:\t{gun.rpm}\n\n[INSERT]\n")
    delay = get_time(gun.rpm) / 1000

    index = 0

    while True:
        while win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(win32con.VK_LBUTTON) and index != len(gun.recoil):
            win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, int(gun.recoil[index][0] * k), int(gun.recoil[index][1] * k), 0, 0)
            index += 1
            time.sleep(delay)

        index = 0

def main():
    k = get_k(800, 0.95)

    ak47 = load_weapon("AK-47", ak47_pattern, 600)
    m4a4 = load_weapon("M4A4", m4a4_pattern, 666)
    ump45 = load_weapon("UMP-45", ump45_pattern, 666)
    
    current_weapon = None  # Armazena a arma atualmente em uso

    while True:
        # Verifica se a tecla NumPad 1 (AK-47) foi pressionada e se a arma atual não é a AK-47
        if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(win32con.VK_NUMPAD1) & 0x8000 and current_weapon != ak47:
            exec_control(ak47, k)
            current_weapon = ak47
        
        # Verifica se a tecla NumPad 2 (M4A4) foi pressionada e se a arma atual não é a M4A4
        elif win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(win32con.VK_NUMPAD2) & 0x8000 and current_weapon != m4a4:
            exec_control(m4a4, k)
            current_weapon = m4a4

        # Verifica se a tecla NumPad 3 (UMP-45) foi pressionada e se a arma atual não é a UMP-45
        elif win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(win32con.VK_NUMPAD3) & 0x8000 and current_weapon != ump45:
            exec_control(ump45, k)
            current_weapon = ump45
                
        time.sleep(0.15)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I tried to adapt it to other keys but it didn't work

what does load_weapon return? An Instance of a gun?

return Weapon(name, recoil, rpm)

please post the relevant code so we can see what load_weapon returns

exec_control has a while True, an endless loop.
This causes your code to stay in this loop, so no new keys are evaluated/read by the code.
Also: I suggest that you use a debugger to step through your code/program during execution. You would have noticed the endless loop (and the other endless loop in main no longer being executed)

I made the adjustment but now it doesn't move anymore

That makes sense: you are using two endless loops, but you don't realise that they don't execute separately. They share the same single thread of execution.
What you might try is: 1) have the "weapon switching"/key reading also be done in the movement loop; 2) reconsider the way you built this program: it is fundamentally not extendable with new features/functionality (it's a mess to maintain, develop ...)

I also have no idea what "the adjustment" is that you're talking about. I only pointed you to the problem, not to what I think you need to do to fix it (only you can know in this case, in my opinion).
